# In AngularJS Factory or Service, do we need to set a "self" or temporary local variable to remember "myself" or "this"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

Short question is: do we need to use `var self = this;` in a AngularJS Factory and Service?

I have seen AngularJS code for factory or service that uses a `var self = this;` to remember itself (the service object), and then inside of the functions of the service object, use `self` to refer to itself.  (kind of like how we are afraid we will lose what `this` is, so we set `self = this` to use it later, by the principle of closure.

However, I have found that we can safely use `this`.  Why?  Because we get back a singleton service object, and when we invoke `myService.getNumber()`, the `this` is bound to the service object `myService`, so it does work.  Example:

If it is a service:

https://jsfiddle.net/yx2s3e72/

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .service("myService", function() {
    console.log("Entering factory");

    this.s = "hello";
    this.getLength = function() {
      return this.s.length;
    };

  })
  .controller("myController", function(myService) {
    console.log("Entering controller");

    var vm = this;
    vm.s = myService.s;
    vm.length = myService.getLength();
  });
```

or if it is a factory:

https://jsfiddle.net/935qmy44/

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .factory("myService", function() {
    console.log("Entering factory");

    return {
      s: "hello",
      getLength: function() {
        return this.s.length;
      }
    };

  })
  // controller code not repeated here...
```

It works too.  So is it true that we really don't need to set a `var self = this;` in a custom AngularJS factory or service?

Comment: In the factory you return object, "this" is in the context of that object. In the service singleton, "this" is bound to the function you have defined, very much like any other function "object" that can be "newed"

Comment: You do if you use other callbacks like inside `then()` of `$q` or `$http` . No different than any other nested function scopes

Answer (score 0):

You may lose the reference to `this`, therefore the reference is saved in the `self` var.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .run(function (MyService) {
    MyService.method();
  })
  .service('MyService', function ($timeout) {
    this.key = 'value';
    this.method = function () {
      console.log(this) // service

      $timeout(function () {
        console.log(this); // window because callback is called from the window
      }, 0);
    }
  });

angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app'), ['myApp']);
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/h12wL81e/)